# jquery running a plugin on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, image-manipulation

I am using [**this plugin**](http://alexmic.github.com/filtrr/) to manipulate some images on a wesbite I am working on.

What should happen is that when the page loads the users see 5 examples images of the filters they can apply to their display picture.
When they decide what effect they want they click on the example and it applies to the bigger image.

My problem is that I cannot get it to work so the user can click another example and have that apply to the big image.

I have made a fiddle with all my code for you to look over, the end results is I need the user to be able to click each thumbnail and see that effect on the larger image. The fiddle is being temporamental at the moment, but the code shows what I am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7Pq7/1/

Comment: Could you add the link to the fiddle?

Comment: where is your fiddle link man?

Comment: Mhmm, the example throws a JavaScript error.